# ImportError: No module named libvirt error whyle trying to install python for libvirt on NetBSD 9.2

Tags: python, compiler-errors, libvirt, netbsd

I've just installed virt-manager with pkgin on NetBSD 9.2 just because I want to emulate the virtual machines with qemu + nvmm on NetBSD 9.2. The installation of virt-manager went ok. But,when I ran it,an error came up :

```
netbsd-marietto# virt-manager

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/pkg/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py", line 386, in <module>

main()

File "/usr/pkg/share/virt-manager/virt-manager.py", line 247, in main

from virtManager import cli

File "/usr/pkg/share/virt-manager/virtManager/cli.py", line 29, in <module>

import libvirt

ImportError: No module named libvirt
```

Googling a little bit maybe I've found the solution here :

https://www.unitedbsd.com/d/285-linux-user-and-netbsd-enthusiast-hoping-to-migrate-some-day

where "kim" said :

Looking at pkgsrc/sysutils/libvirt/PLIST it doesn't look like the package provides any Python bindings -- which is what the "ImportError: No module named libvirt" error message is about. You could try py-libvirt from pkgsrc-wip and see how that works out.

I tried to start the compilation like this :

```
netbsd-marietto# cd /home/mario/Desktop/pkgsrc-wip/py-libvirt
netbsd-marietto# make
```

but I've got this error :

```
make: "/home/mario/Desktop/pkgsrc-wip/py-libvirt/Makefile" line 15: Could not find ../../wip/libvirt/buildlink3.mk
make: "/home/mario/Desktop/pkgsrc-wip/py-libvirt/Makefile" line 16: Could not find ../../lang/python/distutils.mk
make: "/home/mario/Desktop/pkgsrc-wip/py-libvirt/Makefile" line 17: Could not find ../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk
make: Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
```

If u want to see the content of the Makefile,it is :

```
gedit /home/mario/Desktop/pkgsrc-wip/py-libvirt/Makefile

#$NetBSD: Makefile,v 1.32 2018/11/30 09:59:40 adam Exp $

PKGNAME= ${PYPKGPREFIX}-${DISTNAME:S/-python//}
DISTNAME= libvirt-python-5.8.0
CATEGORIES= sysutils python
MASTER_SITES= https://libvirt.org/sources/python/

MAINTAINER= pkgsrc-users@NetBSD.org
HOMEPAGE= https://libvirt.org/sources/python/
COMMENT= libvirt python library
LICENSE= gnu-lgpl-v2

USE_TOOLS+= pkg-config

.include "../../wip/libvirt/buildlink3.mk"
.include "../../lang/python/distutils.mk"
.include "../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk"
```

Can someone help me to fix the error ? very thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting those errors because your copy of *pkgsrc wip* is not inside a *pkgsrc* tree.

Please follow the [pkgsrc wip](https://pkgsrc.org/wip/) documentation to correctly use *pkgsrc wip*. Especially look at the section titled **Getting the "source"**.

In brief, assuming you have a copy of *pkgsrc* in `/usr/pkgsrc` and you want to use `git` to checkout *pkgsrc wip*, run these commands:

```
cd /usr/pkgsrc
git clone git://wip.pkgsrc.org/pkgsrc-wip.git wip
```

Then build `py-libvirt` with these commands:

```
cd /usr/pkgsrc/wip/py-libvirt
make
```

If it builds successfully, you could install it with:

```
cd /usr/pkgsrc/wip/py-libvirt
make install
```

Comment: this is what happens later.....netbsd-marietto# service libvirtd start
libvirtd already running? (pid=598).

Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system.

Client socket identity not available: Function not implemented
Libvirt URI is: qemu:///system
  File "/usr/pkg/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 956, in _do_open    self._backend.open(connectauth.creds_dialog, self)
  File "/usr/pkg/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 172, in open    conn = libvirt.openAuth(self._open_uri,
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 104, in openAuth